# Is there any way to pass/ select a output through a function?

Tags: function, arduino, arguments

I am controlling 4 led using the arduino using millis. I am trying to get the control the same section through 1 generic code and load in variables like what output pin to control. watching through serial I can see it is `analogWrite(13, 255)` however the pin does nothing.

```
 void led_script_effect(......, int red_output , int green_output, int blue_output)
```

where

```
led_script_effect(red_wanted = red_wanted_strip_1, green_wanted = green_wanted_strip_1, blue_wanted = blue_wanted_strip_1)
```

What would be the correct argument to pass in a valid pin output or would the output have to be returned and then within the loop be analog write?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `analogWrite(13,255)` is not working for you is because, pin 13 is **NOT** a PWM pin.

Read more about it in the link below:

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

The use of the sentence 'I am controlling 4 led using the Arduino using millis.' threw me off, but then I realized that you are using the generic function for PWM control on Arduino.

I really think you would benefit from the Arduino code in the Hackster project below:

https://www.hackster.io/devashish-gupta/controlling-led-brightness-using-bolt-and-arduino-2041b9

Comment: I have tried swapping to digital to no change, I am working off  https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/connect-led-light-strips-arduino/     I have then taken there code and created this: if i swap the variable straight to the define the output works correctly. If however i make something else equal to the defined pin no output works. https://github.com/bobthecooldad/5050-LED-Controller/blob/master/_5050_Arduino_COde.ino

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the pins you are trying to control using analogWrite are NOT PWM pins. On the Arduino UNO the analogWrite function only works on pin numbers 3,5,6,9,10 and 11. It is a **HARDWARE** limitation of the Arduino UNO. Even the source you are working off of, is using pin 6, 5 and 9, all of which are PWM pins. Your code will not work for any other pin on the Arduino UNO.